# Ruby Singly Linked List Implementation

Tags: ruby

I'd like to write an `exist` function that returns true if a value exists as a node in a linkedlist and returns false otherwise. So far, I have the following code which always returns true. Any help is appreciated:

```
class SinglyLinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :tail, :count

  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
    @count = 0
  end

  def insert_front(value)
    node = Node.new(value)
    if @head.nil?
    @head = node
    @tail = node
    else
      node.next = @head
      @head = node
    end 
    @count +=1
  end

  def print_first()
    puts head.data
  end

  def print_last()
    puts tail.data
  end

  def exist(value)
    walker = @head
    until walker.nil? 
      if walker.data == value
        return true
      end
      walker = walker.next
    end   
      false
  end

  def size()
    count
  end

end

class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next

  def initialize(data)
    @next = nil 
    @data = data
  end 
end
```

This is my test code:

```
list = SinglyLinkedList.new
list.insert_front(1)
list.exist(2)
```

which returns true.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to test this?

Comment: I just tried the `exist` method and it appears to work. So I'm not seeing the problem you're indicating. BTW, suggested naming convention in Ruby-land would be `exists?`. :)

Comment: ah I just restarted irb and it seems to work for me as well. And thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually, `include?` would be the more common name for your `exist` method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Isn't this basically just an Array, with the insert_front method being the unshift method?

Comment: there is an apparent difference between arrays and linked lists.

Comment: How about you just implement `each` and mix in [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html).  Then `exist` is just an alias for `include?` and you get the rest of Ruby's std collection methods for free. Also, the canonical definition of `tail` for a List is not the last element in the list, but the list excluding head.

Answer (score 1):

Before solution just consider that singly linked list can insert only via `append` to list. You try to insert nodes in wrong direction. 
The problem with you code is that you use reserved method name `next`, just refactor you code and write simple:

```
class SinglyLinkedList
  class Node
    attr_reader :value
    attr_accessor :pointer

    def initialize(value, pointer = nil)
      @value = value
      @pointer = pointer
      @count = 0
    end
  end

  attr_reader :head, :tail

  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end

  def insert(value)
    node = Node.new(value)
    @count += 1

    if @head.nil?
      @head = node
      @tail = node
    else
      @tail.pointer = node
      @tail = node
    end
  end

  def inspect
    return [] unless @head

    values = []
    node = @head

    begin
      values << node.value
      node = node.pointer
    end while node != nil

    values
  end

  def exists?(value)
    return false unless @head

    node = @head

    begin
      node = node.pointer
    end while node != nil && node.value != value

    node.nil?
  end
end
```